# Fast scrolling is not recognized by affix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap for whole website, and i need to have floating sidebar.
Unfortunately, fast scrolling using e.g. "overscroll" method causes bug - when sidebar should have "affix-top" class, it still has just "affix" class.

Also, just a little bit of scrollbar movement fixes problem immediately.
Regular scrolling using mouse wheel or touchpad/trackpoint works perfectly.

Using word "overscroll', i mean the behavior while scrolling using left mouse button, when cursor reaches bottom of the window and some margin (50px?), then scrollbar immediately reaches top.

Comment: I was having an issue that sounds related. It was only on mobile, where fast scrolling would render the header in the incorrect place when you quickly got back to top. I [inspected](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787) it and it had all of the right classes and styles, but the rendering was incorrect. By adding `transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0)` to the `body` tag, the rendering issue was resolved.